# Html5 download attribute...sometimes file name is generic Download.xlsx

Tags: html

I am using Chrome Dev and Chrome canary and the filename of the downloaded file sometimes is called Download.xlsx instead of what I name it.

Sometimes it works great, othertimes its the wrong file name

I am created a detached dom node and firing it

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
        angular.element(link)
            .attr('download', response.data.fileDownloadName)
            .attr('href', 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,' + response.data.fileContents);
        link.click();
```

rendered html:

`<a download="Report.xlsx" href="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQAAAAIAAAAIQD8JIb71AIAA...`

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour your describe happens if `response.data.fileDownloadName` is `undefined`. In that case the generated filename will be `download.extension`. Note however that this would be with a lowercase `d` at least in chrome unlike the `D` you mention in your question.